# Replace part of a column in pd.dataframe for an array with different lengh

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to create a data frame with several columns with different lengths, as I think this is not possible with pd.dataframe I create first a dataframe just with zeros and now I would like to replace each column for an array that I have stored before (with different lengths). I have tried dataframe.replace and dataframe.update but I couldn't get this results.

[image]

The type and shapes of the arrays are:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to insert the array from index `1`. For that you can do,

```
df['dobs'][1:] = dobs
```

Similarly for all the arrays.

Consider a sample dataframe,

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['dobs'] = [0.] * 45
df['dpred_0'] = [0.] * 45
df['dpred'] = [0.] * 45
df['mrec'] = [0.] * 45
```

Now, some place holders arrays of the shape you mentioned in the question,

```
dobs = np.array([x for x in range(1, 45)])
dpred_0 = np.array([x for x in range(1, 45)])
dpred = np.array([x for x in range(1, 45)])
mrec = np.array([x for x in range(1, 46)])
```

Let's check the shapes,

```
print(dobs.shape, dpred_0.shape, dpred.shape, mrec.shape, df.shape) # ((44,), (44,), (44,), (45,), (45, 4))
```

To replace the columns from index `1` for shorter arrays you can do like this,

```
df['dobs'][1:] = dobs
df['dpred_0'][1:] = dpred_0
df['dpred'][1:] = dpred
df['mrec'] = mrec # mrec is of shape (45, ) so no need to start from index 1

   dobs    dpred_0  dpred   mrec
0   0.0      0.0    0.0      1
1   1.0      1.0    1.0      2
2   2.0      2.0    2.0      3
3   3.0      3.0    3.0      4
4   4.0      4.0    4.0      5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an array to a dataframe by creating a new column and define the length and position:

```
random_array = range(0,12)
df['new_column'][0:12] = random_array
```